# Exception '-[GIDSignIn setPresentingViewController:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280e898c0'

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am getting error on `ios` while executing function `GoogleSignin.signIn()` of `react-native-community/google-signin`

[image]

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated, Details and repo for reproducing the issue you can find here.
https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/issues/828

Comment: Have you found the solution? I got similar issue but it crashes upon start.

Comment: No, Have a look at this here.
https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/issues/828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the problem with `react-native-google-signin` the problem was with my previous configurations where i was trying to use google sdk and framework and my project was still using these files instead of using newer version and coco pods,

[Have a look at this how i solved this issue.](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/828#issuecomment-690481715)